# How to deduce that how many solutions for the antiderivative will be.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am thinking there is only one solution at $g(x) = 0$ but I am confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: no, the graph is not a graph of $g$

Comment: enter image description here

Comment: You are asked how many solutions there can be, not how many there are. Use the given graph of the derivative to get the shape of $g$. Then the answer will be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** from the graph, $g'$ is increasing, so $g$ is concave up ($g''>0$). Furthermore, $g'$ has the unique root at $x=0$. What does this tell you about the graph $y=g(x)$? What does this tell you about the point $(0,g(0))$?